# Manage the number of ELSEs in IF-ELSE statement

Tags: r, if-statement

Here's how my data frame looks like:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Period = seq(1:13)
                 , Units = c(1,2,rep(1, 3), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4))
                 , Temperature = rnorm(13, 25, 5)
                 )
```

I want to measure the average Temperature before and after the value of Units has changed. On top of that, I want to measure the averages only if the value of Units has been steady for at least 4 periods before and after the change.

So, here's how I think this process can be broken into parts:

1. Find where each change happens.
2. Check if the the value of Units is equal across the previous 4 and the next 4 Periods. Else - try with the next time the Units changed.
3. If 2 is TRUE - calculate average temperature for these periods.

For the **first step**, I create a variables containing the position of the change in Units:

```
for (i in 1:length(which(diff(df$Units) != 0))){
  assign(paste("change_", i, sep=""), which(diff(df$Units) != 0)[i])
}
```

The **second step**, I check with an IF-ELSE and then nest the **thirds step** inside:

```
if (change_1>=4
  &&(df$Units[change_1] == df$Units[change_1-1])
  && (df$Units[change_1] == df$Units[change_1-2])
  && (df$Units[change_1] == df$Units[change_1-3])
  && (df$Units[change_1] == df$Units[change_1-4])){

  old_mean <- mean(c(df$Temperature[change_1]
                     , df$Temperature[change_1-1]
                     , df$Temperature[change_1-2]
                     , df$Temperature[change_1-3]))

  new_mean <- mean(c(df$Temperature[change_1+1]
                     , df$Temperature[change_1+2]
                     , df$Temperature[change_1+3]
                     , df$Temperature[change_1+4]))
}
```

Naturally, if the first time the change happened, the IF condition is FALSE, then in the *else if* I will check if *change_2* had 4 stable units before and after. So at the end, using the example from above, for the old_mean I want the code to output the result of mean(df$Temperature[6:9]), or 26.22633 .

This is  not optimal, as I want to run this across several data frames, where the number of changes will vary.
Hence, I need to somehow manage the number of else if statements based on how many change_n variables there are.

Can anyone suggest how to automatically tell R how many Else-Ifs there should be?
Additional points if you can suggest a more practical way to do the job.

Comment: Can you add an expected output too please? It often makes following logic flows much easier.

Comment: what is your expected output? it's really hard to follow your way to proceed.

Comment: Please, see my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating a new variable for every time a change happens is not an ideal way to accomplish what you want to do.  In general (i.e., not just when programming in R) if you are thinking about dynamically generating a bunch of variables, you will be better served by creating an array or a vector instead.

In this case,  create a vector which will index every unit that is part of a group of consecutive same-unit types.  Then, with this new vector and the `by()` function, you can get your averages.  Some code to do this would be:

```
rep.threshold <- 4 #variable that will let you change how many repetitions before it "counts"
units.grp <- rep(0,length(df$Units)) #vector of indices for units
grp.id <- 1 #variable to store current index
repeats <- 1 #variable that tracks how many time unit has repeated

for(i in 2:length(df$Units)){
    #if current unit equal to last unit, increment number of repeats counted so far
    if(df$Units[i]==df$Units[i-1]) repeats <- repeats+1

    #otherwise, reset repetition count and increment group if at the end of a running group
    else{
        if(repeats>=rep.threshold) grp.id <- grp.id+1
        repeats<-1
    }

    #if there have been enough repeats, write group index into vectorfor all matches
    if(repeats>=rep.threshold) units.grp[(i-rep.threshold+1):i]<-rep(grp.id,rep.threshold)
}
```

For your example data frame, the above code would generate an vector of `[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]`

Now, you can use `by(df$Temperature, units.grp, mean)` to get the averages for every indexed group, as well (as the average for all temperatures that didn't repeat enough, which will show up as group 0).

Comment: Very nice solution! Can you also suggest what's a clean way of calculating the average for EXACTLY 4 weeks before and after the change happened?

Comment: @NikolayNenov Is the measurement time stored in the data frame as another column?  If not, are the measurements always taken at fixed time-intervals (i.e. one measurement every hour)?